# share specific link to friend's wall

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, share

using facebook c# sdk, I'm able to share link to my wall.

But I have problems when I try to do it on my friend's wall, it show like my friend share link, any ideas why this could be happening?

When I prepare post I'm fill this fields:

from: my facebook client id and name

link: link that I share

post it to address: friends_id/feed

Here is example of code

```
  JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                            {{"link", "{some http address here}"}, 
                                            {"from", sr.Serialize(GetFrom())}};




    FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

    fbClient.PostCompleted += FbClientPostCompleted;

    fbClient.PostTaskAsync("/{ID of my friend}/feed", parameters);
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand? COuld you elaborate a little and maybe provide som code of how you tried to handle this?

Comment: I add example of code how I do this upper

Comment: Whose access token you using?

Comment: I'm use Application Access Token

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the user's access token, not the application access token. After that it should work correctly assuming you have correct publish permissions.

Comment: User's access token expire very quick. How I can catch this event and post message guaranteed?